# Naming deployed jar file with gradle publish?

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We're looking at ditching artifactory and are intending to move to [reposilite](https://github.com/dzikoysk/reposilite), because artifactory is just too big and maintenance-heavy for our small team.

However, when using gradle publish to deploy to reposilite, I am unable to get control of the name of the actual jar. The pushed jar is always named project-x.x.x-{build-number}.jar.
I would like to do it the way the artifactory plugin did it, which deployed a properly named snapshot jar (just project-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT.jar), letting subsequent snapshots of the same version overwrite each other, which is a more convenient arrangement for us for several reasons that I won't go into right now.

Long story short, is there *any* way I can tell gradle publish how to name the deployed jar *exactly*? Our usual setup currently looks like this:

```
configure<PublishingExtension> {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("myproject") {
            from(components["java"])
            groupId = "our.company.myproject"
            artifactId = "myproject"
            artifact(sourceJar)
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = $mavenUser
                password = $mavenPassword
            }
            url = uri("http://localhost:8080/snapshots") # while testing
            authentication {
                create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't really a problem with that configuration. It works. All I want to do is control the exact name of the jar file being deployed in addition to what I'm doing here, and I can't find a way to do it. The jar that is put to the build/libs directory *is* named properly, it's just the publication throwing me a curve ball.